# C++ calling method of subclass in superclass?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reflection, casting

I have an EnemyBullet subclass of superclass Bullet.
Now I'm calling the Bullet method Process() using an EnemyBullet object.
What I want is to determine whether the current object is an EnemyBullet to distinguish from Bullet action.
My code is like this,

```
void Bullet::Process(float deltaTime)
{
// Generic position update, based upon velocity (and time).
m_y = m_y + this->GetVerticalVelocity()*deltaTime;
m_pSprite->SetY(static_cast<int>(m_y));
m_pSprite->SetX(static_cast<int>(m_x));

  if (m_y < 0)
  {
    SetDead(true);
  }

//Here I want to detect current object is an EnemyBullet, then define a different action
//I tried the following code, but it didn't work
if (EnemyBullet* v = static_cast<EnemyBullet*>(Bullet)) {
     if (m_y >800)
    {
      SetDead(true);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You at least want `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`.  But why not just override the method in `EnemyBullet` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for derived type (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355195/check-for-derived-type-c)

Comment: @TavianBarnes I have tried both `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` and did not work. Override would be fine,  but I can't see why my code won't work.

Comment: @Wilheim There's at least one other error as well: you probably meant `..._cast<EnemyBullet*>(this)`

Comment: A base class should not have any knowledge of the existence of any subclass. Use the suggestion of @Tavian Barnes instead, and have the subclass override the relevant method.

Comment: @Wilheim Here's an example of your approach working: https://ideone.com/fG3Ael

Comment: @Wilheim: Is it possible that `Bullet` has no virtual member functions?  In that case, `dynamic_cast` won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of calling a method on an instance of a subclass from a method in the superclass:

```
class Bullet {
public:
  void process() {
    // update m_y...

    // update sprite position...

    if (this->isDead()) {
      // handle dead bullet...
    }
  }

  virtual bool isDead() {
    return (m_y < 0);
  }

protected:
  int m_y;
};

class EnemyBullet : public Bullet {
public:
  bool isDead() override {
    return (m_y > 800);
  }
};
```

Note how each bullet type has custom `isDead` logic.