# How can I verify if I am working with a base or derived object in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class

Let's say I have a class `Product` and a class `AuctionedProduct` which derives from `Product`. I then have a virtual function `foo` that does 'x' if I'm working with a `Product` base class and 'y' if it's actually an `AuctionedProduct`. Given an object, how can I determine which class is actually the one I'm working on?

Comment: If you're designing things right,  you shouldn't have to.  You call the function that is appropriate for the object because it's already created from the correct class.

Comment: please show your code. Usually if you need to know the exact type of a polymorphic object then you dont need polymorphism in the first place

Comment: Instead of describing code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *show* us.

Comment: you can find your answer here : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355195/check-for-derived-type-c)

Comment: You could use `dynamic_cast`, but use of `dynamic_cast` is a code smell

Comment: You say "I have a virtual function `foo`…". Now if it's a virtual function you don't need to determine the class – the runtime system will do that for you and call the right implementation of `foo`.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) ?

Comment: Sorry, i tought posting the code was too much, because im working with three different classes and there would be a looot of codes to show. But i was able to solve it thanks!

Comment: @LouisPopovic "i tought posting the code was too much..." - that is why you should not post your original code, but instead create a [mcve] and post *that*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using inheritance properly, code operating on references of a base class (`Product`), should not need to know the actual type of the object, but interact with each product the same way.

However, if you really would like to know the actual type, e.g: because of debugging, you can use [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
void f(Product* p)
{
  AuctionedProduct* ap = dynamic_cast<AuctionedProduct*>(p);
  if (ap) {
    // we have an AuctionedProduct
  }
  else
  {
    // ap is nullptr, we have a different kind of product
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use virtual methods and use different implementation for base class and derived class and use that method for identify object type.

you can find more decription here :

[Check for derived type (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355195/check-for-derived-type-c)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to use dynamic_cast to find out the object of type like below, dynamic_cast method will return the address of the object if it match with the class type parameter. Also see my comments in the below codes:-

```
class Product{};
class AuctionedProduct : public Product{};
class NonAuctionedProduct : public Product{};

Product *prod1 = new AuctionedProduct();
Product *prod2 = new NonAuctionedProduct();

AuctionedProduct *ac = NULL;
NonAuctionedProduct *nac = NULL;

ac = dynamic_cast<AuctionedProduct*>(prod1);//here it will return the address as prod1 is a type AuctionedProduct
if(ac != NULL )
{
   //ac->dosomething
   cout<<"I am class AuctionedProduct<<endl;
}
nac = dynamic_cast<NonAuctionedProduct*>(*prod2);

if(nac != NULL )
{
   //nac->dosomething
   cout<<"I am class NonAuctionedProduct<<endl;
}

ac = dynamic_cast<AuctionedProduct*>(prod2); //here it will return NULL as prod2 is a object of type NonAuctionedProduct
```