# Is there a design pattern to achieve runtime polymorphism without using dynamic cast for this scenario?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class structure where parent class **P** stores a vector of pointers to child objects of class **C**.

```
class P {
public:

    P() {}

private:
    std:: vector<C*> children;
};
```

Also, child class `C` is a base class and **D**,**E** are derived classes of C. 
D and E have some unique member variables.

```
class C
{
public:
    C() {}

    virtual ~C() {}
    virtual void initialize() = 0;
};

class D : public C {
public:
    void initialize() override;

    //Member variable unique to D
    int value;
};

class E: public C {
public:
    void initialize() override;

    //Member variable unique to E
    std::vector<int> vector_value;
};
```

At runtime, objects of C and D are created and added to parent P's children vector.

At a later time I want to iterate over this vector, determine the object type and use the child's unique member variable.

I know I can achieve this by using a dynamic cast :

```
for( C* child : children)
{
   D* d_child = dynamic_cast<D*>(child);
   if( d_child != nullptr)
   {
      // This object is of type D 
      do something with  d_child->value ...
   }
   else
   {
      // This object is of type E
       do something with  d_child->vector_value...
   }
}
```

However, it is a bad design when we have to check types as iterated by many answers here [Check for derived type (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355195/check-for-derived-type-c)

So I want to know if there is a standard way or a design pattern that will help me achieve this functionality in a better manner?

Comment: Be aware that "At a later time I want to iterate over this vector, determine the object type" isnt really polymorphism. The whole point about polymorphism is that you don't need to know the actual type. In the best case casts should be avoided and the base class should provide the necessary interface (of course sometimes you still need to cast, but that shouldnt be the default)

Comment: You need a method to override.  Your method can handle the intricacies(?). Example: `int C:getNext()` returns next in the vector.  `int D::getNext()` returns the only int it's got. Either way you need to determine when you've hit the last int.  I don't know what your speed req's are but you could make C::vector<int> values that only ever has one value.  Either way, write a method to override.

Comment: FWIW, your base class should provide a complete interface to interact with the derived class.  That lets you just call a virtual function,. instead of mucking about with dynamic cast.

Comment: this is a classical example where polymorphism it's not appropriate as pointed out from @idclev463035818 use composition instead... rethink the design... it will be a mess if you try to change a single comma in the future

Comment: in addition to what others have already said, the way how you described "Parent class P" and "Child class C“ is really confusing. There's no parent/child class relationship between P and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add virtual method in your base class:

```
class C
{
public:
    virtual ~C() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void initialize() = 0; // That one is strange,
                                   // cannot you move initialization in constructor instead?
};

class D : public C {
public:
    void initialize() override;
    void print() override { std::cout << value; }

    //Member variable unique to D
    int value;
};

class E: public C {
public:
    void initialize() override;
    void print() override { for (auto value : vector_value) std::cout << value; }

    //Member variable unique to E
    std::vector<int> vector_value;
};
```

If you begin to add too many method to you base class, then [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might reverse the dependencies. It requires to know each children types though.